# Aqueduct controller subrouting

Tags: aqueduct

Is there any possibility to subroute in Aqueduct controller?

```
router.route("/userApi").link(() => UserController(context));
```

---

```
class UserController extends ResourceController {

@Operation.post("/login")
Future<Response> login(@Bind.body() IdWrap note) async {...}

@Operation.post("/byInnerToken")
Future<Response> login(@Bind.body() IdWrap note) async {...}
```

---

```
post("userApi/login", {"id": "aaa"})
post("userApi/byInnerToken", {"innerToken": "bbb"})
```

Comment: Why not define separate controllers? router.route("/userApi/login").link(() => UserLoginController(context)); router.route("/userApi/byInnerToken").link(() => UserByInnerTokenController(context));

Comment: This is the right solution. I just didn't feel comfortable to have more lines of code than necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, yes, by using path variables.

```
router.route("/userApi/:type").link(() => UserController(context));

class UserController extends ResourceController {
  @Operation.post('type')
  Future<Response> login(@Bind.path('type') String type, @Bind.body() IdWrap note) async {
    switch (type) {
      case "login": return login(note);
      case "byInnerToken": return withToken(note);
      default: return Response.notFound();
    }
  }
}
```

There is no ability to pattern match the contents of the path variable.